# Excel avoid offsetting INDEX of a named range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have several rows that contains data in Excel, like, a, b, c, d and e

I can create a named range of it, say `Letters`. Later in my sheet I want to access those values and say recreate the whole table. However it only takes the aligned value and not from the begining. Explanation

Here is the actual content:

```
+-+-+-------------------+
|a| |                   |
+-+-+-------------------+
|b| |                   |
+-+-+-------------------+
|c| |=INDEX(Letters,0,1)|
+-+-+-------------------+
|d| |=INDEX(Letters,1,1)|
+-+-+-------------------+
|e| |=INDEX(Letters,2,1)|
+-+-+-------------------+
```

What I want:

```
+-+-+----+
|a| |    |
+-+-+----+
|b| |    |
+-+-+----+
|c| |  a |
+-+-+----+
|d| |  b |
+-+-+----+
|e| |  c |
+-+-+----+
```

What I get:

```
+-+-+----+
|a| |    |
+-+-+----+
|b| |    |
+-+-+----+
|c| |  c |
+-+-+----+
|d| |  d |
+-+-+----+
|e| |  e |
+-+-+----+
```

Comment: Letters should start at (1,1) - it works for me, cannot reproduce. That's assuming your tables are correct - which would be *columns* not *rows*.

Comment: Thanks, though when using `=Letters` without index it does as I said

Comment: Right, not using index doesn't allow you to look through the array properly

Answer (score 0):

The only way the reported results and second comment make sense is if, instead of the formulas reported in the first table, which would give something rather different from the reported results, `Vinz243` is actually NOT using the `INDEX()` function at all, just `=Letters`.

That WOULD give the reported result due to implicit intersection, which was very present in 2016, though not now given the change to `SPILL ARRAYS`.

Ergo, that must be what was being done.

So to solve it, the following formulas should have been used:

```
=INDEX(Letters,1,1)
=INDEX(Letters,2,1)
=INDEX(Letters,3,1)
```

which would give "a", then "b", then "c".

A giveaway that `INDEX()` cannot possibly have been being used is that if it had been, the three values returned should have been "a", then "a", and finally "b". Nowadays (2021), the first formula shown would have tried to `SPILL` down with all the entries in `Letters`, but then, if entered normally, would have given just the "upper leftmost" element, "a", and if entered `{CSE}` its result would have been the same as it would have been entered in a single cell, not a range. The following two would have worked as expected. The first one's issue would have been the "0" for the rows parameter, telling `INDEX()` to return all the elements of `Letters`.

Strange to think the poster shows the `INDEX()` formulas, but clearly didn't use them. Odd too, to be cagey about mentioning that fact. But mostly that he knew what to use and even when his alternative idea failed, he did not simply do what he knew would work. Then ask why his alternative idea did not work, not why the whole shadowy thing did not. Ah well, not everyone really wants a useful answer.